# Enroll as an organization on ios

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an iOS Enrollment question.

If I want to enroll as an organization but I don't want the organization name to show up on the App Store (I want to use a brand name instead).
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.

For the very first time when you login to iTunesConnect it will ask you to enter your company name. You can enter whatever you want to display on App Store/iTunes app.

But make sure once you have entered and saved it cannot be changed in the future.

To change you have to discontinue with the current one and purchase the new one with desired name.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Will give it a try.

Comment: Is it possible to enroll as independent and to write a brand name instead of a real name?

Comment: Independent enrollment does not allow this. Independent enrollment will display first and last name. If you want to enroll as an organization then you will require your organization's D-U-N-S.

Comment: I know that. but my will apple dis approve my account if I will write some other name ?

Comment: Mostly yes. Below is the reference which I got: https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/

Try to enroll with your AppleId and you will get warning as per attached screenshot in the main post.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: While enrolling as individual, it will as your name two times. One is the name on your credit card. There you have to enter the name as per credit card.

Second will be your first and last name. There you can try to enter your organization name. Apple will verify it and if it is not as per your country's legal policy then Apple will as you to enter your legal name.

3 years back one of my friend did this and he was successful in this. iTunes store displayed his company name. But this year Apple removed his company name and displayed his first and last name.

You can take a chance.